# how can I validate URL(domain) allowing wildcard(*, %) in java

Tags: java, regex, url-validation

I want to check validate URL allowing wildcard in java.

I found some nice examples about validating URL in java ([REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440758/perfect-url-validation-regex-in-java), [urlValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java)), but those aren't providing the wildcard character.

Here's what I'm practicing:

CODE(urlValidator)

```
public void urlValidiTest(){
    System.out.println(this.urlCheck("https://www.google.com"));
    System.out.println(this.urlCheck("https://google.com"));
    System.out.println(this.urlCheck("*.com"));
}

public boolean urlCheck(String url){
    return new UrlValidator().isValid(url);
}
```

OUTPUT

> true
>
> true
>
> false

CODE(regex)

```
public void regexTest() {
  String[] URLs = new String[] { "http://www.google.com", "http://google.com/","*.com" };
    Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("(?i)^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\\.254|192\\.168)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,}))\\.?)(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\\S*)?$");
    for (String url : URLs) {
        Matcher matcher = REGEX.matcher(url);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

RESULT

> http://www.google.com
>
> http://google.com/

What I want to do is all the above URL is valid.

How should I approach this problem to solve?

Any comment would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATES**

I got rid of the scheme part and added |* and |\.* to the domain part following the answer(|* and |.* gives me a error - invalid escape sequence(valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' ) - but I'm not sure the changes are right).

Now it doesn't allow "google.com"; but allow others("www.google.com", "google.com", ".google.com", ".com")

```
 public void regexValidator(String str){

    Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile(""
            + "(?i)^(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)"
            + "?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\\.254|192\\.168)"
            + "(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])"
            + "(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|"

            //DOMAIN
            + "(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+|\\*)"
            + "(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*"
            //

            + "(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,}))\\.?)"
            + "(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\\S*)?$");

    Matcher _matcher = REGEX.matcher(str);
    if(_matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("[O] " + str);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("[X]" + str);
    }
}

public void validate(){
    System.out.println("TEST START");
    this.regexValidator("https://www.google.com");
    this.regexValidator("www.google.com");
    this.regexValidator("google.com");
    this.regexValidator("*.google.com");
    this.regexValidator("*.com");
    System.out.println("DONE");
}
```

> TEST START
>
> [X] https://www.google.com
>
> [O] www.google.com
>
> [O] google.com
>
> [O] *.google.com
>
> [O] *.com
>
> DONE

Need any help. Thanks.

Comment: From your question and code samples it's not clear what exactly do you want to achieve: test URLs against an address containing wildcards or check that the address with wildcards is correct and can be used to validate URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Take this with a grain of salt, I don't have access to Java right now and did this from the top of my head, so if there are errors in here, feel free to correct me.*

You need to update your regex to include wildcards. That's not trivial, considering how complex that thing is.

**Let's first break down the regex you have:**

```
(?i)
^
    (?:
        (?:
            https?|ftp
        )
        ://
    )
    (?:
        \S+
        (?:
            :\S*
        )?
        @
    )?
    (?:
        (?!
            (?:
                10|127
            )
            (?:
                \.\d{1,3}
            ){3}
        )
        (?!
            (?:
                169\.254|192\.168
            )
            (?:
                \.\d{1,3}
            ){2}
        )
        (?!
            172\.
            (?:
                1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1]
            )
            (?:
                \.\d{1,3}
            ){2}
        )
        (?:
            [1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3]
        )
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]
            )
        ){2}
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                [1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]
            )
        )
        |
        (?:
            (?:
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*
            )*
            [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+
        )
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*
            )*
            [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+
        )*
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}
            )
        )
        \.?
    )
    (?:
        :\d{2,5}
    )?
    (?:
        [/?#]\S*
    )?
$
```

We can now see that there are groups for the scheme, username/password pair (the group with the `@` character), a big group for the domain itself, and a group for a port and one for possible path, query or fragment parts. The big group can be broken down into two parts (separated by `|` (OR)), the first is for IP addresses, with negative look aheads to disallow local IPs, and the latter is for named domains, consisting of one or more parts separated by a dot and finally the TLD.

**So what do you need to do to allow wildcards?** Add a wildcard character (`*` or `%`) in each group that you want to allow to be replaced by a wildcard:

If you want to allow a wildcard for the **scheme**, add one here:

```
    (?:
        (?:
            https?|ftp
            |\*    <-----
        )
        ://
    )
```

If you want to allow wildcards for the **username and/or password parts**, you don't need to do anything, your regex already allows any non-whitespace characters, so `*:*@` or `*@` are already valid.

If you want to allow wildcards for the **domain name**, add them here:

```
        (?:
            (?:
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*
            )*
            [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+
            |\*    <-----
        )
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*
            )*
            [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+
            |\.\*    <-----
        )*
```

If you want to allow a wildcard for the **TLD**, add one here:

```
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}
                |\*    <-----
            )
        )
```

If you want to allow a wildcard for the **port**, add one here:

```
    (?:
        :\d{2,5}
        |:\*    <-----
    )?
```

If you want to allow a wildcard for **paths**, you don't need to do anything, already covered by your regex (`/*` and `/*/*/foobar` etc. are already valid).

And last, but not least, if you want to allow wildcards for **scheme and domain name together** (like in your example), you need to add a new group and OR it in:

```
    |
    (?:
        \*
        \.
        (?:
            [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}
        )
    )
    (?:
        :\d{2,5}
    )?
    (?:
        [/?#]\S*
    )?
```

Basically just add that behind the last group and before the `$` symbol. Don't forget to add a wildcard to the TLD and/or the port here as well, if you want that.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your kind answer.

Comment: But I have to tell you I was so naive when I ask this question. I think the protocol(https, http, ftp) doesn't need to be input. and the 'www' is necessary if there is no asterisk. so if I allow "www.google.com", "*.google.com" and do not allow "https://www.google.com", "google.com", "*.com", how I make the regular expression?

Comment: Please don't use comments to ask further questions. Update your question or ask a new one.